# What's wrong with my calculation for the sphericity of the Disdyakis Triacontahedron?

Tags: geometry, area, volume

I was looking at the [Wikipedia page for Sphericity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphericity), and it lists that of the Disdyakis Triacontahedron at $0.9857$. This makes complete sense. However, I checked the formula for sphericity that they use, which is
$$\Psi=\frac{\pi^{\frac{1}{3}}(6V)^{\frac{2}{3}}}{A}$$ and plugged it into the formulas they use for the volume, which is
$$\frac{180}{11}\sqrt{179-24\sqrt{5}}$$ and the surface area, which is $$\frac{180}{11}(5+4\sqrt{5})$$ and got $0.6836$ instead. Where did my calculation go wrong?

Comment: You'll notice that parts of the table's given volume and area expressions are exchanged in the sphericity calculation, so the information is inconsistent. Since the polyhedron s *very* sphere-like, I suspect that the sphericity value of $0.9857$ is accurate, and thus that the table inadvertently switched the volume and area formulas; [MathWorld seems to confirm that suspicion](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DisdyakisTriacontahedron.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get an answer of about $0.9857$ (with the same exact formula as Wikipedia) if I assume that the two constants in area and volume are swapped: if the disdyakis triacontahedron should actually have
\begin{align}
    V &= \frac{180}{11} (5 + 4\sqrt 5) s^3 \\
    A &= \frac{180}{11} \sqrt{179 - 24 \sqrt 5} s^2
\end{align}
This seems like a plausible mistake to make.

I'm not entirely sure what $s$ is in these formulas, so I can't actually confirm that either of them is correct. Mathematica's `PolyhedronData` command gives the following values for a disdyakis triacontahedron whose *shortest edge length* is $1$:
\begin{align}
    V &= \frac{1}{5} \sqrt{39612 \sqrt{5}+88590} \\
    A &= \sqrt{\frac{22626}{5}+\frac{9738}{\sqrt{5}}}
\end{align}
Using these in the formula for sphericity gives the same result close to $0.9857$ again.